# Custom TableView does not set a custom height for custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

[image]

I am trying to make a custom TableViewCell for a tableview, and the size is 414x350. The problem I am having is when table view get loaded all the sizes are squeezed and not right. I have tried all of the followings:

1. Assigning row height from code

tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 350

tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

2. Assigning row height from storyboard in tableview window
3. Assigning row height from storyboard in tableviewcell window

The result is still the same. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any cell's automatic row dimension to be calculated properly, in your Storyboard you must have a direct line of vertical constraints between every item that goes all the way from the top to the bottom. If you set the constraints yourself, same thing applies.

Don't assign any row heights, except the estimated.